# Filtered Out Values Using "NOT EXISTS" when doing a JOIN with a different table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say I am joining two tables on a column called "Searched" in both tables. However, I want the output to be limited to where that join from my Catalog table is not equal to any value in another third table called Part1 (well actually I am interested in comparing it to about 5 other tables) but at least to get it to work for one for a start. Currently, the query I am running (in MS Access) is outputting nothing, why is that? I was expecting to see a JOIN with 2 columns reduced by the values that are equal between the "Searched" in Cat2 and Part4.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Searches.Search, Cat2.Category
FROM Searches LEFT JOIN Cat2
ON Cat2.Searched = Searches.Search
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Part4.Searched FROM Part4 INNER JOIN Cat2 ON Cat2.Searched = Part4.Searched);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not outputting anything because the `NOT EXISTS` subquery is always returning at least one row.

The reason is because you are doing a `JOIN`, instead of using a correlation clause.  So, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Searches.Search, Cat2.Category
FROM Searches LEFT JOIN
     Cat2
     ON Cat2.Searched = Searches.Search
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Part4
                  WHERE Cat2.Searched = Part4.Searched
                 );
```

The reference `Cat2.Searched` in the subquery now refers to the `Cat2` in the outer query.  That is the logic you are looking for.

For performance, you want indexes on `Part4(Searched)` and `Cat2(Searched, Category)`.

Comment: I am running this query for a good 20-30 minutes already and waiting, Would you expect it to take this long? Not sure how much it matters, my tables are pretty big having around 700K+ rows each...

Comment: I couldn't get this thing to work... it was just running and never came up with any output, not sure why?